# jquery load just freezes the whole web site

Tags: jquery

so my code looks like this.

```
$('#someId').load('SomeController/SomeAction' + ' #someAnotherId', function () {
    console.log('page is loaded');
})
```

As I know this code should take the html inside `#someId`, strip it out and replace it with the html it gets from the server when is makes a request to 'SomeController/SomeAction', but not the whole html, only the part of it which is inside '#someAnotherId'. Now the thing is If I remove the `#someAnotheId` the page is loaded correctly everything works as expected. But in my case I don't what to load the whole html I want to load just a part of it. For that I use the code I've written above, but this code seems to freeze the whole page. I have a ajax waiter configured so when some ajax call is awaiting answer the loading thing appears, and when browser execute the code written above the loading thing appears `console.log()` executed nicely but no content is loaded and the loading thing does not go away either. Any suggestions? any help would be appreciated. (probably you would suggest to only serve the html that I want to load but that would mean to reconstruct my whole infrastructure. that would be very painful).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$.get()` here:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
     var htm = $(data).find('#someAnotherId')[0].outerHTML;//<--updated $(data)
     $('#someId').html(htm);
},"html");
```

#### Update:

change this

```
data.find('#someAnotherId')[0].outerHTML;
```

to this:

```
$(data).find('#someAnotherId')[0].outerHTML;
//^^^^^------wrap it as a jQuery object this way.
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object 'here is the html that server returns' has no method find

Comment: Find cannot actually find the thing I'm looking for. It is undefined. I tried other selectors but it always retrieves undefined. Is there an alternative to find ?